# Flutter Firestore onPressed not writing Future

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to call a future inside of my widget tree to write my userSetup class to my Firestore database. I get no errors running my code but it does not execute the function and nothing gets written to my database. I was wondering how to rectify this so when I press a button, it would write to my database

Here is my userSetup:

```
Future<void> userSetup(final String username, final String displayName,
    final String profilePhoto, final String bio, final String bioLink) async {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid.toString();
  await users.add({
    'uid': uid,
    'displayName': displayName,
    'username': username,
    'profilePhoto': profilePhoto,
    'bio': bio,
    'bioLink': bioLink
  });
  return;
}
```

Here is my button:

```
ElevatedButton(
     style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
      onPressed: () => userSetup(username, displayName, profilePhoto, bio, bioLink),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future userSetup(final String username, final String displayName,
    final String profilePhoto, final String bio, final String bioLink) async {
    
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid.toString();

  return await users.add({
    'uid': uid,
    'displayName': displayName,
    'username': username,
    'profilePhoto': profilePhoto,
    'bio': bio,
    'bioLink': bioLink
  });
```

**edit**:
Try creating an object and then pass it as a parameter to your function:

```
class UserInfo {
 final String username;
 final String displayName;
 ...
 }
```

Comment: I get this error with your code ```LateInitializationError: Field 'username' has not been initialized.
```

Comment: This error implies that you are not passing a value to 'username".

Try creating an object to contain your user information.